# Реализовать меню настроек Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Можете посоветовать, как лучше реализовать по меню?
Попробовал использовать RecycleView, вышло не очень. В плане, если через Recyle, то как можно в одном View все это реализовать, также с пропуском между, "Помощь" и "Наши партнеры" и т.д. Заранее спасибо

[image: пример]

Comment: Можете просто ScrollView использовать

Comment: если количество элементов фиксированное, они входят на один экран, их немного, да еще и имеют разный вид, то использовать виджеты списка (как RecyclerView) нет никакого смысла. ничего, кроме дополнительной и ненужной работы для себя вы не получите. используйте обычную верстку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как сказал @pavlofff, делать данную задачу через RecyclerView, это глупо, я же сказал бы даже извращение, но если список ваших элементов не превышает скажем 20 (цыфра из воздуха на самом деле, важно количество элементов на экране плюс 2 (вроде), потом контейнеры переиспользуются в ресайклерВью что повышает производительность) при использованни нескольких дополнительных элементов вы особо в производительности не потеряете. Есть второй вариант, вы хотите что бы ваше меню было динамичным, то есть в одном месте добавили и оно уже добавилось в менюшку и отлично обрабатывается нажатие (такая мысля меня посетила недавно для одного из развивающихся моих проектов), но как по мне, если ваше меню не будет достаточно динамично меняться (сегодня один список, завтра другой) или приходит из сервака, это ничем кроме как костылём не будет.

Делаем так:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        // кладём сюда все ваши элементы меню
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Ок, я сделал так. Но есть один вопрос, как то можно систематизировать этот процесс? В плане, вот вот вручную все эти элементы прописывать муторно.
[ссылка](https://pastebin.com/MF60L10d) Вот разметка, для одного
То есть вот так описать для каждого пункта

Comment: и как лучше реализовать события на них? это получается, для каждого вью отдельно ставить лисенер на клик

Comment: Увы но других способов я не знаю, ну кроме как это сделать программно через цикл, но честно скажу, такого никогда не делал. Второе это использовать include, вы создаёте разметку (вашего элемента списка) и просто добавляете его через include: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/include.php. P.S. Скажу вам на своём опыте, я не так давно сам был начинающим и также пытался всё как-то систематизировать, но единственное что помогло, это просто делать как получается, а как будет лучше вы уже увидите с опытом.

Comment: P.S.S. Все верстают так. Даже холёные синьёры и именно они так зачастую и рекомендуют верстать (Данная фраза касается именно разметки.).

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать с помощью RecyclerView, создав в нем несколько видов элементов.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Хотя, как было замечено, для такого случая - глупо.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял вы хотите реализовать отображение не просто списка одинаковых вью, а списка который может содержать разные типы View. Поправьте если не так)
Если вы хотите реализовать отображение разных типов View в RecyclerView, то как и сказал Tolikol  вам просто нужно добавить в адаптер для RecyclerView свой ViewHolder для каждого типа вью, обратите отдельное внимание на то, что нужно так же в адаптере для RecyclerView корректно реализовать метод getItemViewType, чтобы адаптер понимал когда ему какой ViewHolder дёргать, попробуйте сделать по ссылке которую скинул Tolikol: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type.
Если что-то будет не получатся или что-то не поймёте - задавайте вопросы уже по этому, подскажу)